# VB.NET/Access - Add duplicate entries for each Student in table and display the total number of duplicates for each student in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

[Dategrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9XZQ.jpg)  [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyG56.jpg)     In the attendance table I have the ID, StudentID, LastName, FirstName, and TrainDate fields.  I enter attendance through a checkbox and datetimepicker.

It creates a record for each date that someone attends class and fills in the fields in that entry.

I can retrieve and display all the records but I want to count/add each duplicate entry for each person and display the total number along with the StudentID, LastName, and FirstName in a datagridview.

I wrote a query in access but it displays all entries and doesn't add them.  I have searched for an answer but haven't found one or recognized it was the answer I did see it.  I used the duplicate entry wizard query.  As I mentioned it returns everything with a duplicate entry.

```
  ' RUN QUERY
    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as Classes FROM TIGTotal")

    ' REPORT & ABORT ON ERRORS
    If NoErrors(True) = False Then End

    ' FILL DATAGRID
    dgvTestDue.DataSource = Access.DBDT
```

Can someone help me either come up with an access query I can use, and SQL statement that will add up eacch persons entries, or another way to get what I need?

Comment: What column value for each entry will be a duplicate? Can you possible show us what the correct answer would look like?

Comment: Is there a way I can post snapshots of my table and what I want the datagrid to look like?  I don't see a way.

The column value is the StudentID.  So here is a really ugly version of what I would like the datagrid to look like.

StudentID        TotalClasses         LastName         FirstName                                       1                             12                   Horton                 Sam                                               2                             15                   Johnson              Dave

Comment: Total classes is what I want to calculate by adding up how many times each student ID shows and then displaying the information for each student in a datagrid view.

Comment: Edit your code original post, and create the table there. It looks a lot nicer. For example, if you have 10 userID's called Jim Davis, and you're trying to count them all, that's what we need to know.

Comment: Ok I attached the pictures.  They are links at the beginning.

Comment: Avoid images to display data, use [text-table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)! Show actual and expected result (text-table too!).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  This got me what I needed.

```
Access.ExecQuery("SELECT COUNT(StudentID) as TotalClasses, FirstName, LastName FROM Attend GROUP BY FirstName, LastName")
```